# How to obtain dataframe based on dynamic subset of values?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe which displays the name of a football team and the values of its shots on target in one game:

```
   Team    ShotsOnTarget         MatchDay   
1  T1           3                   1 
2  T1           5                   2 
3  T1           6                   3 
4  T1           8                   4 
5  T1           9                   5 
6  T1           3                   6 
7  T1           4                   7 
8  T2           4                   1 
9  T2           8                   2  
10 T2           2                   3 
11 T2           6                   4  
12 T2           7                   5 
13 T2           8                   6 
14 T2           3                   7 
.......
```

Starting from match day 3, I want to compute every team's mean shots on target based on only the **last two games** for every match day in the season. For example, at match day 3, the value would be the average of the shots of game 1 & 2, at match day 4, the avg. of game 2 & 3 etc. The end result should be a dataframe that looks like the one below:

```
   Team    ShotsOnTarget.Avg   MatchDay   
1  T1           4                   3 
2  T1           5.5                 4 
3  T1           7                   5 
4  T1           8.5                 6 
5  T1           6                   7 
6  T2           6                   3 
7  T2           5                   4  
8  T2           4                   5 
9  T2           6.5                 6 
10 T2           7.5                 7 
.......
```

Do you have any idea of how to go about this?
I've tried some for-loop-constructs but with no success.
I'm an absolute beginner in R, so I hope my question is clear.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `zoo` package that is really handy with rolling operations. For your case you can do,

```
library(zoo)

stack(as.data.frame((sapply(split(df, df$Team), function(i) rollmean(i$ShotsOnTarget, 2)))))

#   values ind
#1     4.0  T1
#2     5.5  T1
#3     7.0  T1
#4     8.5  T1
#5     6.0  T1
#6     3.5  T1
#7     6.0  T2
#8     5.0  T2
#9     4.0  T2
#10    6.5  T2
#11    7.5  T2
#12    5.5  T2
```

**DATA**

```
structure(list(Team = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("T1", "T2"), class = "factor"), 
    ShotsOnTarget = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 3L), MatchDay = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I'll look into this package more closely.

Answer (score 0):

First I directly thinking of sliding window calculation, which means you can create a window of width 2 and sliding with step 1.

You can find the usage of sliding window average in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3051/mean-of-a-sliding-window-in-r).

According to your example, you need to subgroup the data by Team. Then, apply the sliding window average on top of each subgroup.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. I'll look more closely into this concept.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   Team    ShotsOnTarget         MatchDay   
1  T1           3                   1 
2  T1           5                   2 
3  T1           6                   3 
4  T1           8                   4 
5  T1           9                   5 
6  T1           3                   6 
7  T1           4                   7 
8  T2           4                   1 
9  T2           8                   2  
10 T2           2                   3 
11 T2           6                   4  
12 T2           7                   5 
13 T2           8                   6 
14 T2           3                   7", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Team) %>% 
  arrange(MatchDay) %>% 
  mutate(ShotsOnTarget.Avg = (lag(ShotsOnTarget, 1) + lag(ShotsOnTarget, 2)) / 2) %>% 
  filter(MatchDay > 2)

df
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   Team [2]
   Team  ShotsOnTarget MatchDay ShotsOnTarget.Avg
   <chr>         <int>    <int>             <dbl>
 1 T1                6        3               4  
 2 T2                2        3               6  
 3 T1                8        4               5.5
 4 T2                6        4               5  
 5 T1                9        5               7  
 6 T2                7        5               4  
 7 T1                3        6               8.5
 8 T2                8        6               6.5
 9 T1                4        7               6  
10 T2                3        7               7.5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. So, if I base it on more than the last two games, I would have to add a lag()-function for every additional step I want to go back to?

Comment: I'm afraid yes; or you could try to use an `apply` type function

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Thanks a lot.